# Windows phone 8 -> problems with adding data binding , listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

My problem is that my items won't add to the list. I try to add 3 texts and one image location to the list. I try everything but I couldn't do it.
XAML code

```
<ListBox Name="mylistbox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Name="s1">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="20/"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding naslov}"  Tag="{Binding broj}" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding datum}"   Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>

                                    <Image Source="{Binding slika}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

C# code

```
for (int i = 1; i < datum.Count; ++i)
 {
       podatak _podatak = new podatak();
       _podatak.naslov = naslovi[i];
       _podatak.datum = datum[i];

       _podatak.broj = Convert.ToString(broj);
       _podatak.slika = "http://hsin.hr/images/logo.gif";
       mylistbox.Items.Add(_podatak);
 }
```

Comment: Create a new `List<podatak>`, add all `podatak` variables, set the `ItemSource` of `Listbox` as your newly created `List<podatak>`

Comment: Should I add something in xaml?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test, but I think you are missing one detail, and doing a little mistake.

First: you need to bind a List to a ListBox. So, I believe you should do something like this:

```
List<podatak> myList = new List<podatak>();

for (int i = 1; i < datum.Count; ++i)
 {
       podatak _podatak = new podatak();
       _podatak.naslov = naslovi[i];
       _podatak.datum = datum[i];

       _podatak.broj = Convert.ToString(broj);
       _podatak.slika = "http://hsin.hr/images/logo.gif";

      myList.Add(_podatak);
 }

mylistbox.ItemsSource = myList;
```

And Second: add this on xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="mylistbox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ...
```

**Correcting:**

As commented, doesn't need change anything on your XAML code.
My mistake.

Comment: Remove the XAML bit, it is useless.